# How to move 1 div faster/over a div when the page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I saw this effect  [here](http://abduzeedo.com/).
The  main content section of the page moves over and above a div when the page is scrolled.

I tried recreating this effect using the parallax effect,but in vain.The issue is that using parallax,i can change the speed of 2 objects within the same div only.Also apart from that,i will have to put some unncessary tags  all over the page to make the script work.

Is there a simpler(or working) way to achieve this effect?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can do this with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/MRbWY).

```
#head, #subHead{
    position: fixed;           
    height: 80px;    
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;         /* on top of all */
}

#subHead{
    z-index: 4;          /* below all */
    top: 80px;           /* height of the top div */
}

#content{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;          /* below the top div, but above the one below it */
    margin-top: 160px;   /* the height of the two divs above combined */
}
```

And to make subHead scroll slower:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev){
  var subHead = document.getElementById('subHead'),
      topHeight = document.getElementById('head').offsetHeight;

  subHead.style.top = (topHeight - document.body.scrollTop / 4) + 'px';
};
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){  
  $('#subHead').css('top', ($('#head').height() - $('body').scrollTop() / 4));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton,specially for the latter part.Why did u use "i" "can" "has"...i know the websites admin :)

Comment: `$.on` is not available in jQuery 1.6. Include a newer jQuery version, or [use `$.bind` instead](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfd2R/)

Answer (score 2):

There definitely seems to be some parallax going on at least. I haven't looked through the markup thoroughly enough, but one thing of note is that the area with the graphic and the content area (along with the area for the ads) are sibling `<div>`s.

Just top of head, with some CSS `position`ing and `z-index`ing, it'd be a bit straightforward to render the content `<div>` above the graphic `<div>`. It seems that only the graphic `<div>` is being controlled via parallax scrolling. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could attach onscroll event for your first div and set scroll position of second div in your JS.

```
<div id="div1" onscroll="OnScrollDiv()">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function OnScrollDiv () {
    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    div2.scrollTop = div1.scrollTop * 2;
}
```

More info in here:
http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php
http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php

Comment: is there anything apart from the above code we need to add to make it work?http://jsfiddle.net/ETuTg/ feel free to tell me that i am dumb for any mistake in that code

Comment: On jsfiddle did not worked for me... I created a sample html page on my local pc, here is the contents of it: http://pastebin.com/9qSB5K0U

Try to run it on your local machine, check whether it works. I added alert just to check the scroll values.