# What css technique is used to get this effect?

Tags: css, layout

So I've noticed a style used in a few designs lately that gives the appearance of static background images with a content overlay that reveals and hides the images on scroll. It's difficult to describe the effect but you can see it [here](http://12hrs.net/#up) and [here](http://www.googleventures.com/). It's almost like there is two layers to the design. Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: This is called parallax scrolling.  You can do it with JS, or by abusing perspective with 3D transforms.

Comment: [maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799820/how-to-move-1-div-faster-over-a-div-when-the-page-is-scrolled/14799926) ?

Comment: for the shown effect on the google venture page you don't need javascript. The top part is fixed and the scrolling part has a relative position with a higher z-index. It's all only a question of positioning.

Comment: @SLaks both examples work with JS disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with javascript - You could look into the stellar.js library. You use it with [jQuery](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://jquery.com/&ei=1DCBUeuKDsW52AW77oCgDw&usg=AFQjCNFA7CZ5sWRDhHPuipmhL7zVksjC2A&bvm=bv.45921128,d.b2I) to handle parallax scrolling for elements or backgrounds or both.

http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/

It will help you handle parallax scrolling and keeps certain functionality for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help as well [curtain.js](https://github.com/victa/curtain.js) its not maintained anymore, but its a great plugin still if you look at the demo sites!